# Spring Batch remote partitioning across multiple remote servers

Tags: spring, spring-batch, partitioning

I'm writing a proof-of-concept (POC) which simulates SBF step partitioning discussed here (Partitioning a Step (single or multi process)): https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html

However, I'm struggling to find examples anywhere showing how to configure a master step with multiple slave steps on remote servers. The only examples I see use the broker url as the
        tcp://localhost:61616

Does anyone know how to configure multiple slave remote servers?

I've checked several links but I'm only allowed to post 2:
https://github.com/mminella/java-remote-partitioning

Comment: To clarify- I'm trying to run a single step, within a job, on other servers.

Comment: What messaging middleware are you using?

Comment: @Michael Minella maybe that's the problem- I'm not using any middleware.

I've been following your example on GitHub https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/resources/jms-context.xml

but have struggled to find any code samples on how to get the remote slave servers connected to the master.